# Can not get data from controllers using Express NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I need to get data from two controllers, but when I call them, returns this error:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Plus, I want to know if I must write all the logic inside the try section. This is my code:

[UPDATED from Shariful Islam Mubin's reply]

**DataMatching: controller that matches user tags and activities**

```
const { response } = require('express');
const { userData } = require("./userData");
const { getActivities } = require("./activities");

const DataMatching = async (req, res = response) => {
  let userTags = [];
  let activities = [];
  let state = false;
  let topActivities= {};

  try {
    userTags = await userData(req, res);
    activities = await getActivities(req, res);

    if (userTags.data.tags && activities){
     userTags = userTags.data.tags;
     state = true;
     //doSomething
    }
    return res.json({
      ok: state,
      response: topActivities
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
    ok: state,
    response: error
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  DataMatching
}
```

**userData: controller that gets user data**

```
const { response } = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const userData = async (req, res = response) => {
  try {
    let res_user = await axios.get(somePath, someConfig)

    if (res_user.data.success === true) {
      return res.json({
        ok: true,
        response: res_user.data
      })
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({
        ok: false,
        error: res_user.data.message
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      ok: true,
      response: res_user
    })
  }
}

module.exports = {
  userData
}
```

**getActivities: controller that gets activities data**

```
const { response } = require('express');
const Activity = require('../models/activity');

const getActivities = async (req, res = response) => {
  const activities = await Activity.find().populate('tags')

  try {
    return res.json({
      ok: true,
      activities
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      error: error
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you call `res` object, you must have to `return` it. Because, `res` or `response` object sends data to the client. And you cannot return anything after sending a response to the client.

So, you've to write

```
return res.json({/*.. YOUR_CODE_GOES_HERE ..*/})
```

and,

```
return res.status(500).json({/*.. YOUR_CODE_GOES_HERE ..*/})
```

I also noticed you called other 2 functions which are also responsible for responding to the client. You shouldn't do that.

- Try to return response only from the requested controller, which may be `DataMatching` function in this case.
- Youu can wrap all code inside `DataMatching` function in a `try-catch` block to handle any exception that occurs in the function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated my code to include all inside the try section, but since those 2 functions are working for another things too... what should I do if I want to keep those responses?

Comment: Separate your core logic from those 2 functions. Otherwise, it'll be really hard to find out and fixing the bugs.